# trying to link css in html file for a django project

Tags: html, css, django, web

[Directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pV8Qf.png)

Attached is a photo of my directories. Am am trying to use sudokuStyle.css in sudoku_board.html. However, it does not seem to make the connection in my html file. I am including my head for the HTML.

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sudoku Solver</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/sudokuStyle.css' %}">

</head>
```

Where could I be going wrong?

I have tried a variety of ways to connect but it does not work.

EDIT:

this is my urls.py

```
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views
    
    
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.sudoku_board, name='sudoku_board'),
    ]
    
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

this is in my setting.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/css/'
```

Comment: Make sure you have added the `STATIC_URL` and all necessary settings for static files. And also include this `urlpatterns = [
    # your other URL patterns here
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` in project's urls.py

Comment: Look in the webserver access log to see what actual url it is using to fetch the css file.  Is that the correct url?  What status code was returned by that request (200? 404?)

Answer (score 0):

Please post all the necessary code next time in order to make it easier to understand the problem. It seems to me that in the settings you might not have added static to urlpatterns

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Also check if the file names and their paths are correct.

Comment: i added this but my code still does not work. i added some more info to my code if you can see where i went wrong. i am pretty sure my file names are correct.

Comment: @Minion try to ```STATIC_URL = '/static/'```